# Rundeck project and job sync between 2 instances with backend as mysql cluster

Tags: virtual-machine, mysql-cluster, rundeck

I have set up 2 rundecks in 2 VMs and mysql cluster so Rundeck #1 on VM#1 connects to Mysql DB#1 and similarly Rundeck #2 on VM#2 connects to Mysql DB#2.

The problem now I have is whenever I am creating a project / job in rundeck #1 that I am not able to see it in rundeck #2. What should I do?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be fixed by maintaining the default engine in my.cnf.
So in my case I just modified the /etc/my.cnf

Introduced the following option below the header [mysqld]:

default-storage-engine=NDBCLUSTER

And did a mysql restart and the tables sync started to happen.

delete the rundeck db before proceeding with any modifications.

Thanks and hope this helps everyone facing such issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to switch the databases, i.e. Rundeck#2 connects to MySql DB#1 to see if the jobs are visible.

If this is the case, then you have a sync issue.

If jobs are still not visible, then i assume that there are some identification problems of the Rundeck instances.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I setup a mysql cluster which works fine as the database created in one gets reflected in another...but when i configured rundeck db it also got reflected in another data node... now when i create a project and jobs in one rundeck then it is not reflecting in another.. can pls you help me with the issue?

Comment: @KronnorK Good, so the DB setup is correct. I believe these pointers can help you moving forward: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/757 & https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rundeck-discuss/aXkDkNeTEp0

Comment: Got it working... I had to change the Engine to ndbcluster... that made it working

Comment: Glad to hear that. It would be nice if you post your answer here and accept it, so others can benefit too.